# Matlab and websites

Tags: matlab, web-applications, image-processing, web, neural-network

I have a project where I will utilizing image processing and neural networks. The tool that I am using for this is matlab. The system is a web based system and the examples I have seen and worked with is currently desktop based. Does anyone know how I would create a website layer on top of the image processing and neural network part?

The simplest structure would be something like

Web site -> Provide input -> Process through image processing and neural networks -> Provide output in the website

While this would work, additionally if possible I would also like to have the website more interactive with the process, like when I wan't to control the intensity for some threshold in some part regarding image processing

Additionally I also require to write to a database, mysql if possible

It would be a bonus if I could combine Java EE with matlab as I already have code which I can use from java. Howeve the mandatory requirement is that I create a website which can get the job done

Regards,
Milinda

Comment: Getting the website to invoke Matlab can probably be done with php [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) (though there is probably a better way). Transferring data between the website and Matlab could be done with MySQL - there are some interfaces on the Matlab File Exchange for that.

Comment: If you can switch from Matlab to R you can use [rApache](http://rapache.net/)

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for the job is using the [Matlab Java Builder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/), which can compile Matlab scripts into Java classes.

That way, you can use the processing parts written in Matlab directly in Java server layer. You also don't have to worry about database access in Matlab, which can (and usually is) pretty messy. You just do all the number crunching in Matlab, and data handling and web interface and Java.

The downside is that Matlab Java Builder is a component standalone from the core Matlab package and has to be bought separately.